# How to populate dynamically a grid on WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, grid

this is my very first program in WP7, so i have some issues.

I'm trying to populate a grid with an list of objects that has been bought by another method. Here what i made so far:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private List<Row> lsResult;
    private Grid myGrid = new Grid();
    private int i = 0;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ColumnDefinition colData = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition colOcorrencia = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition colSituacao = new ColumnDefinition();
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colData);
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colOcorrencia);
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colSituacao);
        myGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        myGrid.Background = myBrush;
        gridResult = myGrid;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        i = 0;
        lsResult = null;
        lsResult = Rastrear.Busca(txtNumber.Text);
        foreach (Row r in lsResult)
        {
            RowDefinition rNewRow = new RowDefinition();
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rNewRow);

            TextBlock lblData = new TextBlock();
            lblData.Text = r.Data.ToString();
            lblData.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            lblData.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(lblData, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(lblData, i);

            TextBlock lblOcorrencia = new TextBlock();
            lblOcorrencia.Text = r.Ocorrencia.ToString() ;
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(lblOcorrencia, 2);
            Grid.SetRow(lblOcorrencia, i);

            TextBlock lblSituacao = new TextBlock();
            lblSituacao.Text = r.Situacao.ToString();
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(lblSituacao, 3);
            Grid.SetRow(lblSituacao, i);
            i++;

            myGrid.Children.Add(lblData);
            myGrid.Children.Add(lblOcorrencia);
            myGrid.Children.Add(lblSituacao);   
        }
        gridResult = myGrid;

    }
}
```

The method Buscar() is returning the list as it should, but when i click on the button it doesn't do anything, not even the paint to white on the constructor happens actually.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some pretty shady stuff in your code behind that i'm used to seeing and should be done in xaml. Change this

```
gridResult = myGrid;
```

to

```
gridResult.Children.Add(myGrid);
```

I don't think you can just change references of static UI elements like that.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But there's another problem, the page doesn't get populated when the button is pressed.

Comment: It worked, but the page doesn't get populated : ) ? Try adding lengths and widths do all your column and row definitions eq. rNewRow.Height = new GridLength(100); colData.Width = new GridLength(100);